# Different margin bottom for first page TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

I'm doing this PDF page, and on the first page there is a footer image and it overlapped with the content, so I want to change the first page margin bottom only to a bigger number so that it won't overlap with the footer image, the coding is as follow but it is not working

```
// set auto page breaks
$pageN = $pdf->PageNo();
if($pageN == 1):
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 100);
else:
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by initially setting a larger margin with SetAutoPageBreak(), then setting it to a smaller margin after drawing the footer on the first page. This appears to achieve the results you are looking for, but there are likely better ways to accomplish this result.

Here is an example that extends the TCPDF class:

```php
<?php
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom footer.
class MYPDF extends TCPDF
{
    public function Footer()
    {
        if ($this->page == 1) {
            $this->SetY(-45);
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page 1 Footer', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
            // Set a smaller margin after drawing the first page footer.
            $this->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
        } else {
            $this->SetY(-15);
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page 2+ Footer', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        }
    }
}
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
// Set a large margin for the first auto bage break.
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM + 40);
$pdf->AddPage();
$txt = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. ';
$pdf->Write(0, str_repeat($txt, 400), '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```